# Symfony2 FOSUserBundle change fos_user id type

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

I have problem. I have to change type of fos_user.id to bigint. But I don't know how to do it. I have overriden the FOSUserBundle and I have tried code below, it's works but not for id.:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="sf_guard_user")
 * @ORM\AttributeOverrides({
 *      @ORM\AttributeOverride(name="id", column=@ORM\Column(type="bigint", name="id")),
 *      @ORM\AttributeOverride(name="email", column=@ORM\Column(type="string", name="email_address", length=255)),
 * })
 */
class User extends BaseUser implements EncoderAwareInterface {
 //...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to override `id`. It should be defined in class that extends `FOS\UserBundle\Model\User`. Just define it inside your `User` class. Like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="sf_guard_user")
 * @ORM\AttributeOverrides({
 *      @ORM\AttributeOverride(name="email", column=@ORM\Column(type="string", name="email_address", length=255)),
 * })
 */
class User extends BaseUser implements EncoderAwareInterface {
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="bigint")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

 //...
}
```